# Alignment with \mbox in one line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

In my MWE below, I included an `\mbox` in my `\align` environment.  I wanted the text line to be flush left, but when I inclued the text line as a separate line, all the equations got shifted to the right.  How can I bascially include the `\mbox` in one line, then continue with the rest of the formula in the `align` environment?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,fourier,physics}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mbox{Now ~} \dfrac{1}{z!}  = & (z!)^{-1} \\
\ln p(z)  = & z\ln\lambda - \lambda - \ln z! \nonumber \\
\mbox{Differentiating with respect to $\lambda$, we have}\nonumber \\
\pdv{\ln p(z)}{\lambda} = & \dfrac{z}{\lambda} - 1
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Load `mathtools` rather than `amsmath`. Use `\text{..}` rather than `\mbox{..}` in usual places. And, in case you want one whole line (or paragraph) in between math use `\intertext{..}` or `\shortintertext{..}`.

Comment: The `&` should be *before* the `=` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `&` goes before the relation so it gets the correct spacing
- use `\text` rather than `\mbox`
- load `mathtools` (which in turn loads `amsmath`) and use `\intertext{..}` to get a whole paragraph in between

[image: photo]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools,fourier,physics}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \text{Now} \quad \frac{1}{z!}  &= (z!)^{-1} \\
  \ln p(z) &= z\ln\lambda - \lambda - \ln z! \nonumber \\
\intertext{Differentiating with respect to $\lambda$, we have}
  \pdv{\ln p(z)}{\lambda} &= \dfrac{z}{\lambda} - 1
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\intertext` seems to be a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,fourier,physics}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mbox{Now ~} \dfrac{1}{z!}  = & (z!)^{-1} \\
\ln p(z)  = & z\ln\lambda - \lambda - \ln z! \nonumber \\
\intertext{Differentiating with respect to $\lambda$, we have}
\pdv{\ln p(z)}{\lambda} = & \dfrac{z}{\lambda} - 1
\end{align}

\end{document}
```